# Convert forloop to foreach in Perl

Tags: perl

I have used `for($j=2;$j<@slice1[$i];$j++)` in my problem.

How can I use `foreach` for the above statement?

Comment: `foreach my $j (2..@slice1[$i])`?

Comment: `foreach $j (2 .. $slice1[$j]-1) { }`?

Comment: Actually i have to calculate prime number between 1 to 1000. I have done this using for loop but in the next question i have to solve the above problem using foreach. How can i do this

Comment: Question is, what do *you* think that `@slice1[$i]` does? That is a scalar value, written as though someone thinks it is an array, something which issues the warning `Scalar value @slice1[2] better written as $slice1[2] at`, unless you have warnings turned off (a very bad thing to do).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would work:

```
for my $j (2..$slice1[$i]-1)
```

Comment: Actually i have to calculate prime number between 1 to 1000. I have done this using for loop but in the next question i have to solve the above problem using foreach. How can i do this

Comment: Change the `for` into `foreach`; they are [synonyms](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If his teacher told him to use "foreach", they probably meant to use Perl style `for`, not just to switch one synonym for another.

Comment: @TLP: yes, I know — I hope he does, too, and that his teacher knows too.